# How can I get EditText change?

Tags: android, listener, android-edittext

I have a EditText and I want to inform each time text changes (with entering each character). What implementation should I use and what function should I override?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `addTextChangedListener` method on your EditText and make your class implement or define an inner class implementing the `TextWatcher` class:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener(android.text.TextWatcher)

Comment: Make sure you handle the delete key being pressed while the `EditText` is empty: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13983097/832776

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a boolean variable as false and at each time et.edited make it true