# How to get the simultaneous value of the two EditText in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to set the Edittext as like, whatever i write and enter in to the EditText, it should be written in to the TextView at the same Moment.

I think it can be possible by adding any istener.
I am not able to implement it. So Please anyone help me in this . ?
thanks.

```
 includedText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                if(!(includedText.getText().toString().equals("")))
                {
                    double included = Double.parseDouble(includedText.getText().toString());
                    included = roundTwoDecimals(included);
        //          double amountValue = (excluded*15/100);

                    String amt = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(included-(included/1.15)));
                    String excluded = String.valueOf(included/1.15);
                    System.out.println("The Amount is: "+amt);
                    amountText.setText(amt);
                    try{
                        excludedText.setText(excluded); //////// Error
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    amountText.setText("");
                    //excludedText.setText("");
                }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    excludedText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if(!(excludedText.getText().toString().equals("")))
            {
                double excluded = Double.parseDouble(excludedText.getText().toString());
                excluded = roundTwoDecimals(excluded);
        //      double amountValue = (excluded*15/100);

                String amt = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(excluded*0.15));
                String included = String.valueOf(roundTwoDecimals(excluded+(excluded*0.15)));
                System.out.println("The Amount is: "+amt);
                amountText.setText(amt);
                includedText.setText(included);
            }
            else
            {
                amountText.setText("");
                includedText.setText("");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });
```

Logcat:

```
    10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662): java.lang.StackOverflowError
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.reflow(DynamicLayout.java:261)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.text.DynamicLayout.<init>(DynamicLayout.java:150)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.makeNewLayout(TextView.java:4851)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5348)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2688)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:66)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:110)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:66)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:110)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:66)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:110)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:66)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:110)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$1.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:66)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:75)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at com.project.TaxCalculator.GSTActivity$2.onTextChanged(GSTActivity.java:110)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:6131)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2691)
10-08 10:34:27.239: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(662):     at android.widget.TextVie
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the addTextChangedListener method on your EditText and make your class implement or define an inner class implementing the TextWatcher class:

```
textMessage = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.textMessage);
    textMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){}
    });
```

For more :: [Android: How can I get EditText change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304075/android-how-can-i-get-edittext-change)

Comment: If i have two Edit Text in One Layout and for both i want to add this listener then what should i have to do ?

Comment: just put down double listener

Comment: double listener means ? You mean i have to implements TextWatcher for two times ??

Comment: ya exactly same thing two time

Comment: I am using two editText for such listener. and on enter of both the edittext the value is change of respective EditText and the TextView. But on implementing both i got Stackoverflow Error.

Comment: Hello, Will you please tell me where is the problem in my code ??

Comment: Please see the Edited question for logcat.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have edited My Question with implementing the try and catch() in code. And also have edited the logcat which i got after the applying the try block. Now where i am wrong ?? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
TextView mTextView= (TextView )findViewById(R.id.textview);
EditText mEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edittext);
    mEditText .addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
      mTextView.setText(s.toString);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement android.text.method.Keylistener 
where you get varios callback methods. Choose a method as per your needs.

Enjoy..