# OnWrite in a TextView

Tags: android, keyboard

I have a TextView and I want to control when the user insert a letter.

```
Ex.

s -> search s in database and show results
st -> search st in database and show results
sta -> search sta in database and show results
stac -> search stac in database and show results
stack -> search stack in database and show results
...
...
...
```

How I can do this ?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304075/android-how-can-i-get-edittext-change

Comment: You many need to use TextChangedListener with textWatcher. see this discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4310525/android-on-edittext-changed-listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [TextWatcher](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html) to get Text when user enter any text in EditText

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

                        String text = searchText.getText().toString();
                        if (text != null && text.length() > 0) {
                                                // Call your method that will get Data from Database and then update then data to the ListView or anything you want
                            getSearchDataFromDBagianUserText(text); 
                        }

                }

                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                        int after) {
                }

                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

                }
            });
```