# How to take data from an edit text and times it against a spinner value - dynamic update?

Tags: android, text, spinner, edit

I'm trying to make a simple order system. So the user selects a burger type from a spinner, then the user can enter in the quantity and then there is some math taking place in the background which sets a text view at the bottom with the total price. I'm not sure what method I'm meant to use so that it is updated dynamically when the user changes the text view quantity.

If i just say that all burgers are 2.50, i need some sort of method saying, if/when data is entered into the edit text , take that data and then times it by 2.50 and set it in the total text view below. I'm just unsure on the method part of it so it's dynamic and will change when the edit text quantity is altered.

[code]

```
package placeorder.com;

import java.util.Random;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;

public class Food extends Activity {

    String[] burgersarray, chipsarray, saladarray;
    Random order = new Random();
    double bquantity, hamburger, burgertotal;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.food);

        EditText burgerquantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_burger);          
        TextView total = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_total);
        Spinner burgers = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_burgers);      

        burgersarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.burgers);
        chipsarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.chips);
        saladarray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.salad);      
        TextView orderid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_orderid);        

        int randomorder = order.nextInt(9999);
        orderid.setText("Order ID: " + randomorder);        


        ArrayAdapter<String> burgersadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, burgersarray);

        burgers.setAdapter(burgersadapter);


        burgers.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()

        {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {

                String burger = (String) arg0.getSelectedItem();    
            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            }
        });     





    }



}
```

[/code]

Comment: make a look at this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304075/android-how-can-i-get-edittext-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to implement a `TextWatcher` for your `EditText`. First make an array that will hold the prices of the burgers(mapping the burgers types from the spinner) and an `int` field that will hold the current selection from the spinner:

```
double[] prices = {1d, 2d, 3d};
int currentSelection = 0;
```

then implement the `TextWatcher` for your `EditText`:

```
burgerquantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                double result = Integer.parseInt(s.toString())
                        * prices[currentSelection]; //obtain the total
                total.setText("" + result); //set the result
            }
```

Also in your spinner listener set the currentSelection field:

```
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    currentSelection = arg2;
//this is needed because the user could enter a value in the EditText but change to another burger category and so you update the total for the new price
                    if (!burgerquantity.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                        double result = Integer.parseInt(burgerquantity.getText()
                                .toString()) * prices[currentSelection];
                        total.setText("" + result);
                    }
                }
            });
```

NOTE: You'll have to take care about the exception that could arise when parsing the value from the `EditText`(for example if the user enters a value and then deletes all the numbers you'll have an exception because the app will try to parse an empty string)

Comment: It's giving me red lines for "addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()"

All it says is "change to remove text", also are these meant to be outside the oncreate?

Comment: @EdBriscoe No, except for the `prices` and `currentSelection` fields put the rest IN the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: Okay thanks, just getting issues with

"addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()" now.

"Text Watch cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: @EdBriscoe It's the http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html . Add `import android.text.TextWatcher;` at the top of your activity near the other imports.

Comment: Sweet it works!! :-D Thank you so much, whoever you are thank you.!!!!! I wish you good karma!!

Surely I don't need that If statement? If i take that out it will just allow no value in the edit text?

Comment: @EdBriscoe Actually you need it. When the spinner is shown it will automatically start a `onItemSelected` event. At that time the `EditText` is empty and the call `Integer.parseInt` will throw an `Exception`(trying to parse an empty string). You can test it :). Take care about what the user enters in that `EditText` so you don't have exceptions when you parse it as numbers. Also if my answer helped you please upvote it and mark it as correct with the check.

Comment: Okay, so is there anyway to get around having a blank field?

Also can you explain to me what the arguments mean in the onItemSelected?

Comment: @EdBriscoe The solution is to check what you have in the `EditText` before you try anything and if it is empty then don't parse it and simply set the total to 0. The parameters are hard to explain if you don't know much about android, the important part is that the `int arg2` is the position of the selected row in the spinner, if you select the row 4 then `arg2` will be 5(the counting starts at 0)

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I cannot vote and stuff because of my rating

Comment: How would I extend this if I have 1 other spinner, so for example, a salad option as well. Because the total values are only gonna be private to those methods no?

Comment: @EdBriscoe Just make `result` a field in your class and simply add the `saladTotal`(for the salad spinner): `result = Integer.parseInt(s.toString())
                        * prices[currentSelection]; //obtain the total
                total.setText("" + (result + saladTotal));`

Comment: I tried to have a go but I'm confused and couldn't get it working.

Do you have an email address I can email the code to?

Comment: What does the 'private' and 'final' bit mean?

Comment: @EdBriscoe It's basic java , you should read a tutorial about java http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html